# Counting occurrences of each word in a sentence

Tags: c#, interview-questions

I have been doing this test task for C# Developer role at UBS.London recently and have been rejected. No reason stated yet. Was wondering if you can take a look and provide feedback on what I can do to improve solution. The task description is below and solution itself is on GitHub. Also attached code for two main classes I have implemented. Unit tests are in solution. No UI provided as I thought it is not required as Unit tests are self explanatory.

Hope it will be helpful for someone else doing interviews for C# Dev roles.

[Exercise description](https://github.com/andreynikulin/TextParsing/blob/master/README.md)

> Create a .net application that will solve the following problem. There
>   are no time constraints and you are free to use any resources at your
>   disposal.
>
> The Problem As an author I want to know the number of times each word
>   appears in a sentence So that I can make sure I'm not repeating myself
>
> Acceptance Criteria Given a sentence When the program is run Then I'm
>   returned a distinct list of words in the sentence and the number of
>   times they have occurred
>
> Example Input: "This is a statement, and so is this." Output: this - 2
>   is – 2 a – 1 statement – 1 and – 1 so - 1

[Solution is on GitHub](https://github.com/andreynikulin/TextParsing)

[I am also using Netfx-Guard library from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/netfx-Guard/)

Solutions contains two projects: main project with `SentenceParser` and `StringSplitter` classes and unit testing projects.

`SentenceParser` and `StringSplitter` classes are below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UBS.TextParsing.Interfaces;

namespace UBS.TextParsing
{
    public class SentenceParser
    {
        private IStringSplitter _splitter;

        public SentenceParser(IStringSplitter splitter)
        {
            _splitter = splitter;
        }

        public IDictionary<string, int> Parse(string sentence)
        {
            Guard.NotNullOrEmpty(() => sentence, sentence);

            var words = _splitter.SplitIntoWords(sentence);

            var wordsCounts = from word in words
                group word by word.ToLower()
                into g
                select new {Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

            return wordsCounts.ToDictionary(wc => wc.Word, wc => wc.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `StringSplitter` class which splits sentence into words.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UBS.TextParsing.Interfaces;

namespace UBS.TextParsing
{
    public class StringSplitter : IStringSplitter
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoWords(string sentence)
        {
            Guard.NotNull(() => sentence, sentence);

            var stringList = new List<string>();

            var currentWordSb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var chr in sentence)
            {
                if (Char.IsPunctuation(chr) || Char.IsSeparator(chr) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(chr))
                {
                    AddToList(currentWordSb, stringList);
                    currentWordSb.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    currentWordSb.Append(chr);
                }
            }

            AddToList(currentWordSb, stringList);

            return stringList;
        }

        private void AddToList(StringBuilder stringBuilder, ICollection<string> collection)
        {
            var word = stringBuilder.ToString();
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                collection.Add(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the usage also.

Comment: Added using statements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> Guard.NotNullOrEmpty(() => sentence, sentence);
> ```

This introduces a dependency on a third-party library, which is 100 lines. Why not just write

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
{
    throw new ...
}
```

---

The `ISplitter` interface is overkill. As is the `StringSplitter` class, probably -- as @NickUdell mentioned, a regular expression looks like the right tool for the job here.

---

You have the core of the solution right here:

> ```
>       var words = _splitter.SplitIntoWords(sentence);
>
>        var wordsCounts = from word in words
>            group word by word.ToLower()
>            into g
>            select new {Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count()};
>
>        return wordsCounts.ToDictionary(wc => wc.Word, wc => wc.Count);
> ```

Which can be simplified to

```
var words = _splitter.SplitIntoWords(sentence.ToLower());
return words.GroupBy(word => word)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

Besides being a little shorter, we are creating fewer objects. Let's say there are \$n\$ words returned by `SplitIntoWords`, \$d\$ of which are distinct (up to case). The first version creates \$2n\$ string objects (the \$n\$ returned by `SplitIntoWords` and these same \$n\$ words lower-cased) and \$d\$ instances of the anonymous type. The second version creates \$n + 1\$ string objects. This might not be a concern, but since it's an easy win, we should just take it.

---

`SplitIntoWords` could be written using `yield`. Again, not a big difference but it makes the code a bit more re-usable, since client code can use `Take`, `First`, etc without having to have generate every word in the string.

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoWords(string sentence)
{
    var word = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var chr in sentence)
    {
        if (Char.IsPunctuation(chr) || Char.IsSeparator(chr) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(chr))
        {
            if (word.Length > 0)
            {
                yield return word.ToString();
                word.Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            word.Append(chr);
        }
    }

    if (word.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return word.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do it with RegEx initially, but found that I would need to list all possible delimiter characters in reg expression in order to split sentence, so decided just to go with current solution.

Comment: LINQ query over ext. methods I think is just matter of personal preference.

Comment: What is wrong with using third party libraries? We are not writing unit test framework every time we start project, right?

Comment: In this case, the third party library comes off as overkill, when the home-grown approach is literally 4-6 lines. Personally, I disagree, as I build my projects under the assumption that they will later be expanded upon, but this could come off as overengineering the problem.

Comment: @gemasp - The regex string "\p{L}+\b" is your friend here.  It's not 100% perfect if you want to deal with contractions but you could work that in without too much difficulty.

Comment: Another issue with the library usage is that the test is wrong...  An empty string should just return an empty result set - not throw an exception (or whatever `Guard` does.)

Comment: @gemasp `What is wrong with using third party libraries?` There is a benefit (not reinventing the wheel), there is a cost (dependency + more libraries to load). In the mentioned case, you get no benefit (since a fairly equivalent snippet handles the same thing without the library) but all of the cost (dependency + having to load the library). That means it's not a good approach. You're right that _other_ instances (like a unit testing framework) can be good, **since the benefits outweigh the costs**.

Answer (score 6):

**Naming**

It's unwise to include types in your naming, unless it's unavoidable.

`var stringList = new List<string>();`

The variable name tells us nothing about it's purpose. It's a list of strings? Of course it is, that's what the data type is!

Instead you should name it:

`var words = new List<string>();`

Because that's what it actually represents.

Additionally your function `AddStringToList` isn't very helpful. Firstly, it's not even taking a `List` parameter, it's a `Collection`, and secondly, you don't mention that it actually gets a string from the `StringBuilder` parameter and adds it to the list.

**Comments**

You haven't commented anywhere. It's probably unnecessary to add metadata comments to the functions here, unless you're building a documentation file, but since it's an interview question you should be going all out.

**Code**

I have no idea what your guard statement looks like, but what is the reasoning behind passing in an `Action` that gets the `sentence` variable along with the `sentence` variable itself?

**EDIT:** Upon looking at the full source it appears to be from an external library.

Is there any reason why you don't use `Regex` here? It's kinda what it was designed for. Most of your string splitting code could be replaced with a single `Regex.Split` call, or even a couple of `string.Split` calls.

Your method `AddToList` doesn't depend on any instance data and so should be static. In fact, the entire class could be static, if it wasn't for the fact you built it to an interface.

**Globalization**

You should specify a `CultureInfo` for your `.ToLower` calls. For this, I recommend `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` since you're dealing with word that will be shown on screen. There is some argument for `InvariantCulture` because you're performing comparisons on them. I find it unlikely the culture would change during execution, but to be safest, it would be best to cache the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` before execution.

**The Good**

You're coding to interfaces, you're trying to stay DRY (even if I doubt the helpfulness of `AddToList`), using LINQ and guarding your arguments. That's already a great starting point.

Comment: Can you expand on "even if I doubt the helpfulness of AddToList" please?

Comment: My problem with `AddToList` is that it is unintuitive. The method name hides that it's getting the text from a string builder as opposed to adding the `StringBuilder` itself, and beyond that it offers little extra functionality compared to the `List`'s `Add` method. I don't like changing a parameter and not returning it but I think that's personal preference. If you really want this as a method, I'd change it so the param is a string, rename it to `AddIfNotNullOrEmpty`, make it an extension method of `Collection` and use it with `stringList.AddIfNotNullOrEmpty(stringBuilder.ToString())`.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of the solution should be to get a distinct list of **words** and the number of occurance in the sentence.

**SplitIntoWords() method**

The code is iterating over each character inside the `String` sentence and checks if the character is either a `punctuation`, a `separation character` or a `white space` character. If this is true, you assume the end of a word.

A better approach would have been to check if `Char.IsLetter()` and if that is not true the end of a word is reached. In this way not only the speratation, punctuation and white space is handled but also digits, control characters etc.

**AddToList() method**

For interview coding tests you should always use braces `{}` also for single `if` statements.

**Parse() method**

The checking with `Guard.NotNullOrEmpty()` should at least be replaced with `Guard.NotNull()`, as this is the only case where an exception should be thrown.

But as mjolka alreday said, it would be better to use the built in methods. Also consider that for an input parameter which only holds whitespace an empty `Dictionary<String,int>` should be returned.
So this should be changed to

```
if (sentence == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("sentence"); }
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sentence)) { return new Dictionary<String, int>(); }
```

You are calling `word.ToLower()` on each word you got from the call of the `SplitIntoWords()` method. It would be better to call the `ToLower()` method of the provided input parameter.

Comment: SplitIntoWords() method: I may argue that word123 should be considered as whole word in context of my sentence.

Comment: @gemasp And what about "99 bottles of whiskey" ? And a check for `IsLetter()` is faster as a check for 3 conditions. About `Guard` if you show in an interview that you also know the built in methods it shows your knowledge about the language itself. Here a comment about the `Guard` class would a good and shows that you also know about testing frameworks etc.

Comment: Why is it better to use built-in methods if there is such a brilliant class as Guard? You are not writing a unit testing framework for each new project you starting, right?

Comment: I have moved ToLower() method to word.ToLower() from sentence.ToLower() because I couldn't come up with correct unit test to test call to ToLower() at that time. Basically I discovered that all my unit tests are passing if I just remove call sentence.ToLower(). So to make this call ToLower() testable I moved it to current position. I could be wrong here.

Comment: What about "99 bottles of whiskey"? Checked just now and StringSplitter works perfectly for this sentence.

Comment: "Here a comment about the Guard class would a good and shows that you also know about testing frameworks etc." didn't get that. What do you mean?

Comment: If you use the built in methods (because they are sufficient for only 2 checks) you can add a comment to the code, that you prefer to use the `Guard` class for bigger projects.

Answer (score 3):

your naming makes me stop and think much harder than I should...

```
foreach (var chr in sentence)
```

are you iterating over each character, in the sentence?  looking at this I think logically I would iterate through the words of the sentence and then the characters of the words...  so this confuses me a little.

your parameter shouldn't be `sentence` it should be something like `inputString` or `stringToBeSplit`.

and the variable in the foreach statement should be `character` instead of `chr` just to be absolutely clear that you are iteration by character.  heck, I would even go as far as saying you could have saved it also by writing it like this

```
foreach (char chr in sentence)
```

a `string` is a `char` array so it will allow you to do this.

---

Instead of all that fun stuff, let's get rid of all the punctuation to begin with

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should use this to replace

- Commas
- Periods
- Double and single quotes
- Parenthesis
- Brackets
- etc.

I would probably make this a Static Method in which you can code all of these in and call it on the entire sentence, and a Regex Replace might do well here to limit the number of lines of code inside this (new)method.

Again, this should be done before you try to split the sentence into words. it wouldn't make sense to try and split on punctuation in the Sentence.

---

Then, I would use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and create a string array, maybe create a dictionary of the distinct words from the first array, then loop through the first loop and increment an integer value the corresponds to that word in the dictionary.

When you are done looping then print out your Dictionary.

Looks like this is what you were doing, but then you loop through the Sentence character by character and that doesn't make sense; you have characters, then you have words, then you have sentences, then you have Paragraphs, then you pages, then chapters, then it can go to acts or sections and then books.  you skipped from characters to Sentences... Why?

I imagine that you were worried about contractions, that should be a `word-level` function/method to tell other word objects being compared to it that there are actually 2 words inside that object.

You should create a word object(class) and create some operator overloads for it, so that you can compare contractions with non-contractions (`don't = do` or `don't = not`) where it should be counted in 2 columns.

you have the general idea of how to do it, but you went off on that one weird tangent. at least I would say it's tangential.

---

Now comes the issue with breaking the sentences out of the paragraphs.

You receive a big blob of text, so [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) it on periods (*as long as you are certain there will not be any laying around in numbers....of course you could exclude the numbers from the start as well*).

You could still run the initial Punctuation Replace before you separate into Sentences by excluding Periods from the punctuation list.